# Set child inside child class list value from main class

Tags: c#, .net

Check the code bellow. I want to set List value to `StorageFileDisplay` class from `MainFolderDisplay` class. So what i am trying to do in controller is-
`var mainFolder` initialise `MainFolderDisplay` class then trying to get access of `SubFolderDisplay` inside list called- `StorageFileDisplay` then i am trying to set new value to this `StorageFileDisplay` list. But the problem with current code is it just cant access `mainFolder.SubFolderDisplay.StorageFileDisplay` and throwing exception-

> instance is not set to an instance of an object

Anyone can tell me how can i add value to `SubFolderDisplay.StorageFileDisplay.StorageFileDisplay` list from the main calss called- `MainFolderDisplay`? Thanks in advance

Controller:

```
var mainFolder = new MainFolderDisplay();

mainFolder.SubFolderDisplay.StorageFileDisplay.Add(new StorageFileDisplay
{
    AwsUniqueFileName = "foo",
    FileId = 0,
    FolderType = 0,
    RelatedFolderId = 0,
    UserDisplayFileName = "foo",
    UserId = 0,
});
```

Model:

```
using Test.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.ViewModels
{
    public class MainFolderDisplay
    {
        public int MainFolderId { get; set; }
        public string MainFolderName { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public List<StorageFileDisplay> StorageFileDisplay { get; set; }
        public List<SubFolderDisplay> SubFolderDisplay { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubFolderDisplay
    {
        public int SubFolderId { get; set; }
        public string SubFolderName { get; set; }
        public int MainFolderId { get; set; }
        public List<StorageFileDisplay> StorageFileDisplay { get; set; }
    }

    public class StorageFileDisplay
    {

        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public string AwsUniqueFileName { get; set; }
        public string UserDisplayFileName { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int FolderType { get; set; }
        public int RelatedFolderId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception is telling you exactly which error you have made. Consider this: You have to, and in fact you do, create a `MainFolderDisplay` so you can use it, so why would not have to create a `SubFolderDisplay` in order to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate all the nested properties as well, they are null by default. Try this:

```
var mainFolder = new MainFolderDisplay
{
    SubFolderDisplay = new List<SubFolderDisplay>
    {
        new SubFolderDisplay
        {
            StorageFileDisplay = new List<StorageFileDisplay>
            {
                new StorageFileDisplay
                {
                    AwsUniqueFileName = "foo",
                    FileId = 0,
                    FolderType = 0,
                    RelatedFolderId = 0,
                    UserDisplayFileName = "foo",
                    UserId = 0,
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Instance is not set to an instance of an object.

This is clearly saying that you are trying to execute an operation on something which is actually null.

That means your  `StorageFileDisplay` and `SubFolderDisplay` lists in `MainFolderDisplay` object are null. So first you have to initialize these lists. You can do it as follows in the `MainFolderDisplay` class:

```
public class MainFolderDisplay
{
        public MainFolderDisplay()
        {
            StorageFileDisplay = new List<StorageFileDisplay>();
            SubFolderDisplay = new List<SubFolderDisplay>();
        }
        public int MainFolderId { get; set; }
        public string MainFolderName { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public List<StorageFileDisplay> StorageFileDisplay { get; set; }
        public List<SubFolderDisplay> SubFolderDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think SubFolderDisplay or StorageFileDisplay lists are not instantiated. Ensure that before adding

```
new List<SubFolderDisplay>()
new List<StorageFileDisplay>()
```